# What libraries are supported by contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, c++, library

What libraries can be used when writing a contract in C++? What are the limitations? If I have a library I normally use and like, how do I compile it for use by contracts?

Answer (score 3):

Contracts are in WASM which is a compiled binary language. The only currently tested and validated language for EOS smart contract development is C++, but in theory any language that compiles down to WASM can be used.  There is an active community effort to support TypeScript as well.

Comment: I think expaand is asking about which C++ libraries they can use, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking. And what limitations are there, if any?

Comment: I know boost comes included and supported. STL of course.  There is a library of contracts that comes included which has contracts for social media, an exchange, a token contract, etc.  Then there is a library of objects as well.

Comment: @Nat, aware of the system token contract, but where are the others you mention, like an exchange?

Comment: @WalterK https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts looks like they've removed the exchange contract. Feel free to go back to a previous release to find it.

Answer (score 3):

The code for Boost is in https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/tree/master/libraries/boost

The main EOS library is eosiolib, and it uses Boost in action.hpp, dispatcher, datastream, etc.